# Laravel 8 project is giving serialize error

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

When I use the `php artisan serve` command, the project gives the following error.

> Laravel\SerializableClosure\Exceptions\InvalidSignatureException Your
> serialized closure might have been modified or it's unsafe to be
> unserialized.

What is the reason for that? How can I solve this?

Comment: have generated application key ?

Comment: how can i generated application key ?  
Bhargav Rangani

Comment: php artisan key:generate run this command

Comment: Yes I run now ,but still error is not resolved Bhargav Rangani

Comment: php artisan route:clear run this command and restart your Laravel server

Comment: Thanks. Problem is resolved with php artisan route:clear. Bhargav Rangani

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, but resolved it in two steps.

First: run this command;

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Second: run this command;

```
php artisan optimize
```

Issue resolved.